# NDB datastore. How to tell the difference between a default value and one that has not been set

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I created a new Boolean property on a model called 'blank' with default value False.

I want to go back and set ones that have not been set. But I don't want to update new ones that have been added and actually set to the default False.

When I print out the object I don't see 'blank' in it's output.

But if I do

```
obj.blank
```

I see 'False'.

So really I just want to be able to find out - is the False actually set on this obj or is it just returning the default.

Any way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you had the default set from the very beginning, this will guarantee that the property is not missing, even if the user didn't update/changed it. So I'm guessing that you added this value afterwards. I would suggest you to have batch task or something to run through your entities and just `put()` so it will actually set the default value if it's missing.

Having said that, I'm not sure if it's possible to check it afterwards.

Comment: Understanding the schemaless nature of the Datastore is key to why these answers are correct. The older entities still exist, they simply don't have the property, at all. "None" will be falsy enough for a conditional test like "if", although I'm doubting that the property exists on the object and actually *has* the value "False" as OP implies.

Answer (score 1):

Every entity saved before the change does not have the blank property saved in the datastore.

When you get one of those entities and ask for the blank property you should have None as the result.

```
getattr(entity_saved_before_change, 'blank') == None   # this returns True

isinstance(getattr(entity_saved_after_change, 'blank'), bool) == True   # this returns True
```

So, just check for the value being None.